# Can 'operation' be accepted?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, vocabulary, cloze-test

This is a comprehension cloze question for 11 year olds:

> His only hope for cure was a bone marrow transplant. His brother was chosen to donate some of his bone marrow. The ________ would  take place in the States.

Was told that 'transplant' and 'procedure' can be accepted but 'operation' cannot because patient won't be cut.

Is it really so?

Comment: Certainly "procedure" is the more general & encompassing term, but, as commonly understood, "operation" could apply since anesthesia would be used and the two bodies would be "violated" with catheters larger than a typical hypodermic needle.

Comment: (I've had over a dozen "procedures" to remove kidney stones, and while a surgeon never used a scalpel on me in any of them, I would defy you to claim that they could not be called "operations" -- operating table, general anesthesia, surgeon doing the work, several nurses and technicians assisting.)

Answer (score 5):

The relevant definition of *operation* in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) doesn't mention cutting as a prerequisite:

> **operation** *n* ... **4 :** a procedure performed on a living body usu. with  instruments esp. for the repair of damage or the restoration of health

Under the *Eleventh Collegiate*'s definition, a bone marrow transplant would certainly be an operation; in fact, it might be viewed as two operations—one on the donor and one on the recipient. Any more-precise notion of the meaning of *operation* as a medical term of art involves a more sophisticated understanding of the term than Merriam-Webster seems to possess, and I think it is asking a lot of an eleven-year-old to be expected to possess it.

This is not to say that the operation in question may not also be characterized as a procedure.

Answer (score 2):

### Eh, kinda.

If these were all given as multiple choice answers,

> A. Transplant B. Procedure C. Operation D. [Sth Obviously Wrong]

then—having just looked up [what actually occurs during a bone marrow transplant](https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/health/treatment-tests-and-therapies/bone-marrow-transplantation)—**B *is* the best answer**. A isn't wrong but repeats the word too quickly to sound as good as a synonym. C is what I would've chosen, based on my misunderstanding that marrow was actually transplanted from a bone in one person to a bone in another. As is, apparently the only thing they do is extract marrow through a long needle and then inject it into the recipient's bloodstream, waiting weeks for it to find its way to some bone and start doing something useful. That really does comport better with *procedure* than *operation*, although [*operation* is not actually synonymous with *surgery*](http://www.differencebetween.net/science/health/difference-between-surgery-and-operation) and it's a ridiculously fine point to make with 11-year-old ESL students, unless it's a premed magnet program for [Doogie Howser](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doogie_Howser,_M.D.) clones.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @SvenYargs, "operation" is fine.

However, you may say:

> "The **transplantation** would take place in the States".

Comparing the 2 nouns "transplant" and "transplantation", my feeling is that the noun "transplant" better fits to the therapeutic method and that "transplatation" relates more to the operation.

Answer (score -1):

An operation is generally understood to be a procedure that is performed by a surgeon.

And a surgeon is the person who generally does the cutting, as you put it.

So with that in mind, I would agree with the person who gave you the advice.

Comment: You probably need to say in this answer that a bone-marrow transplant usually doesn't need and isn't performed by a surgeon. You obviously know that, but if a reader thinks that it may be because they don't know what the procedure entails, this answer isn't very clear.

Comment: Peripheral blood stem cell [(PBSC)](https://bethematch.org/Support-the-Cause/Donate-bone-marrow/Donation-process/Donating-PBSC/)  donation is a nonsurgical procedure to collect blood-forming cells for bone marrow transplants. [Bone marrow donation](https://bethematch.org/Support-the-Cause/Donate-bone-marrow/Donation-process/Donating-bone-marrow/)  is a surgical procedure that takes place in a hospital operating room.

Comment: You need some sources for your answer. eg. dictionary definitions.